# Input string was not in a correct format - GUID error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, guid

I'm using ASP.NET (C#) and I have code which inserts a new row into a database.  When I run it, I get the error "Input string was not in a correct format".

I think I have narrowed this error down to the users GUID uniqueidentifier, which needs to be passed into the insert statement. (created from the asp:login)

I know I can call for this UserID by using `Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey.ToString()`
but then I need to convert back to a Guid using `new Guid(string)`

This doesn't seem to work for me.  Here is my code-behind: Can you spot any errors??

```
public partial class LoggedIn_CreateDoc : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection sqlConn;
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDA;
    DataSet ds;
    String strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["1722555Connection"].ConnectionString;

    protected void createDoc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();

        connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["1722555Connection"].ConnectionString;
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

        string commandText = "INSERT INTO Documents (Name, Description, RcdID, Location, AccessLevel, DateCreated, AuthorID, DocStatus, EngStatus, QaStatus, DesignStatus) VALUES(@Name, @Description, @RCD, @Location 1, @Date, @AuthorID, 1, 1, 4, 4)";
        cmd.CommandText = commandText;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RCD", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AuthorID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);

        cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = TextBoxDocTitle.Text;
        cmd.Parameters["@Description"].Value = TextBoxDocDescription.Text;
        cmd.Parameters["@RCD"].Value = ListBoxSeries.DataValueField;
        cmd.Parameters["@Location"].Value = ListBoxLocation.DataValueField;
        cmd.Parameters["@Date"].Value = DateTime.Now;
        cmd.Parameters["@AuthorID"].Value = new Guid(Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey.ToString());

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();

        Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Your new document has been created. \n You can now find it in your Task Panel!');</script>");

        Response.Redirect("TaskPanel.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is this a custom membership provider? Can you give an example of the output of ProviderUserKey.ToString()? As an aside, your SqlConnection should be in a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx) block as your connection won't be getting closed here (apologies if this is just example code)

Comment: Here is a sample of what is produced from the ProvideUserKey.ToString: " 1f6b8431-ae07-4563-b0d2-904f0e5d2d63 " - I am using asp:login, in its simplest form.

Comment: Does `cmd.Parameters["@AuthorID"].Value = Guid.Parse(Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey.ToString());` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the problem is your `ProviderUserKey`. The cast doesn't fail - the insert does.

Do you need to convert `RCD` and `Location` to int values? You are currently trying to pass strings to int fields.

You should use `ListBox.SelectedValue` to retrieve the selected values from these fields, after which you can use `Int32.TryParse` to convert them to integers (or `Int32.Parse` if you want an exception thrown should the cast fail).

`ListBox.DataValueField` is not used to retrieve the selected value from the `ListBox`, but to tell it what field in the bound datasource it should treat as its value and - as such - it is the *name* of a field, not the value within it.

Comment: I just after figuring this out!!! I'm using the following to get the value: ListBoxLocation.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["LocationID"].ColumnName.ToString(); Now I just need to convert to int :)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Currently you're trying to store the name of the column as the value in the column.

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see what values are being assigned to all the cmd.Parameters, and make sure those values agree with the data type and restrictions of the columns in the database.